# Does Particle Designer work with SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, particles

It's says on [their website](https://71squared.com/particledesigner) that support is coming, but other people have said it already works. Does anyone know as I would like to know before purchasing it. If it doesn't support SpriteKit does anyone know if there is an alternative?

Comment: They have a Try-button on their web site.

Comment: I just upvoted because I didn't know that software and I'm very interested on it (and on the answer for your question).

Comment: @Mikael The trail doesn't allow you to export it so I still don't know if it can be used in SpriteKit.

Comment: @KieranCrown oh ok. Damn it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about application compatibility. Support questions should be directed at the app developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been and are still issues with sprite kit on the Mac which has slowed down our ability to support SK in Particle Designer. We are still working on support as well as also providing our own particle system to use with SK which will help if the SK bugs are not fixed quickly. Our own particle system for SK will support all the systems currently available in PD. We are testing at the moment and hope to release our own particle system soon.

Comment: Any news regarding SpriteKit support? Looks like that system, you where talking about, was never released?